# Can't send eth to to contract using the Remix environment

Tags: contract-development, ether, fallback-function

I have followed the steps of the [solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function) to preform the work of fallback function.My code is below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    uint x;

    function () payable {
    }
}

contract Send {
    function sendtest() returns(bool ) {
        Test t = new Test();
        bool res = t.send(100 ether);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The result of t.send() is false.I don't know what's wrong with it.Whether I use the instance of contract insteading of the contract address or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked in remix for me, you just need to add the payable function. On the  '100 ether' tag too,  using wei is considered best practice (or msg.value)

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    uint x;

    function () payable {
    }
}

contract Send {

    function sendtest() payable returns(bool ) {
        Test t = new Test();
        require(msg.value>0);
        bool res = t.send(msg.value);
        return res;

    }

}
```

Comment: I have run this code, but it got a exception. My purpose is sending ethers to the Test contract, so I don't know why I need to add payable to the `sendtest` function.

Comment: oh, It really works well. I just forgot to set the value of `value`. But can you explain why it is necessary to add `payable` to `sendtest` function?

Comment: Well you just can't send ether to a function unless it's payable.  Adding this allows the sendtest to hold the money and then for it to send the money to the other contract.  If you want to send it directly from your account, you can create another function.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you want to send ethers to your contract, Right?
Give this code a try.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Test {
    function () payable {}
}
contract Send {
    function sendtest() payable(returns bool){
        bool res = this.address.send(msg.value);
        return res
    }
}
```

When you call `sendTest` with some value, this value is transferred to contract. `this` refers to contract and hence `this.address` represents contract address.

The line `this.address.send(msg.value)` transfers the msg.value to the contract and this line `function () payable {}` allows contract to recieve ethers.

Comment: Can you explain why it is necessary to add the payable to `sendtest` function? Is it just the recevier function need this modifier?

Comment: You can send ethers to a function unless it's payable. So in order to send ethers to sendTest you have to add payable modifier.

Comment: But my intention is to send ethers to Test contract,You code is sending ethers to Send constrct.